# Concatenate two group_concat queries in MySQL

Tags: mysql

What I want to do is weird! I want to group_concat one of the column values grouped by two different columns. Which will give me two results with two columns each. After that I want to join & concat the group_concat values from those two results so that I can find one result.
My table

```
x  y1  y2
----------
a  1  2
b  2  3
c  4  3
```

I want something like

```
x     y
----------
a     1
a,b   2
b,c   3
c     4
```

I can group_concat the x values grouped by y1 and y2 with two different queries. I can not join and concat them at the same time. Help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just want to "unpivot" the data using `union all` and then do the aggregation:

```
select y, group_concat(x) as xs
from ((select x, y1 as y from t
      ) union all
      (select x, y2 as y from t
      )
     ) t
group by y
```

Comment: Thank you so very much. You just saved my day. I just thought it in a bit complex way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use union all tha  the select for group by

```
select x, group_concat(y) from (
  select y1 as y, x
  from my_table 
  union all
  select y2, x
  from mu_table ) t
group by x
```